# how to install pyhook for python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, pyhook

I tried to install Pyhook using .whl files from
 [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

I also tried to install it through `pip install pyhook`
and is show me this :

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyhook
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pyhook
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\MOHSENE\pip\pip.log
```

there is other method work with python 3.4 can i use it?

Comment: What was wrong with `.whl` file? [edit] your question and show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are no downloadable files at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook) so `pip install pyhook` doesn't work.

Download a wheel from [SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/pyhook/) or [w32 pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) and install from that wheel with command `pip install pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl`.

Comment: So there is no other method to insall pyhook